# How to get all properties of the current class and NOT its parent(s) in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, object, reflection

How do I get an array of all the properties of the current class, excluding inherited properties?

Comment: The properties that you don't want in your child class, you make them private in the parent. Could you please elaborate what you are trying to do with the array of properties?

Comment: check if late static binding helpful. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Laravel Job classes function as a DTO. If they're queueable however, they inherit two extra properties from a trait used by its parents. Would be nice if there was a native function to eliminate the parent class properties to have only the DTO's values for easier processing. I can't just exclude them by name because it might break with future laravel updates where more might be added or their names might change.

Comment: I agree with @Jigar; if you need to do this, then writing it with inheritance was a mistake in the first place. You can achieve similar results to what you're looking for without needing to break the basic concepts of OOP by writing your classes using the decorator pattern or simply with nested objects.

Answer (score 11):

You can reach it only with reflection, here suitable example:

```
<?php

class foo
{
    protected $propery1;
}

class boo extends foo
{
    private $propery2;
    protected $propery3;
    public $propery4;
}

$reflect = new ReflectionClass('boo');
$props = $reflect->getProperties();
$ownProps = [];
foreach ($props as $prop) {
    if ($prop->class === 'boo') {
        $ownProps[] = $prop->getName();
    }
}

var_export($ownProps);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'propery2',
  1 => 'propery3',
  2 => 'propery4',
)
```

Answer (score 8):

In PHP >= 5.3

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('DerivedClass');  
$ownProps = array_filter($ref->getProperties(), function($property) {
    return $property->class == 'DerivedClass'; 
});  

print_r($ownProps);
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($className); // get class object
$properties = $class->getProperties(); // get class properties
$ownProperties = array();

foreach ($properties as $property) {
  // skip inherited properties
  if ($property->getDeclaringClass()->getName() !== $class->getName()) {
    continue;
  }

  $ownProperties[] = $property->getName();
}

print_r($ownProperties;
```