# php, how to get all private variables EXCEPT inherited ones?

Tags: php, reflection

```
Class A
{
    Private $a;
}

Class B extends A
{
    Private $b;

    Public function list()
    {
        Var_dump($this);
    }

(New B())->list()
```

It will print even variables from `A`. I want to get variables only from `B`. How to do it?

Comment: Given that `list` is a reserved word, have you actually run this code?

Comment: @iainn `list` can be class method name.

Comment: You can't. See documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
BTW - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You have to use the ReflectionClass Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848998/how-to-get-all-properties-of-the-current-class-and-not-its-parents-in-php

Comment: @u_mulder Ah, so it can. Didn't realise that had changed in PHP 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection you can do this, for example:

```
Class A
{
    Private $a;
    Protected $e;
}

Class B extends A
{
    Private $b;
    Private $d;

    Protected $c;

    Public function list()
    {
        $ref = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        $ownProps = array_filter($ref->getProperties(), function($property) {
            return $property->class == __CLASS__ && $property->isPrivate();
        });

        print_r($ownProps);
    }
}

(New B())->list();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => b
            [class] => B
        )

    [1] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => d
            [class] => B
        )

)
```

Comment: yea, fine. Altough if you filter by ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE in getProperties() and skip the ->isPrivate() method, it becomes twice faster