# Yii2: How to get attributes of $this?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Model class A and a subclass B.

```
class A extends \yii\base\Model {
    public $a1,$a2;
}

class B extends A {
    public $b1,$b2;
}

$o = new B();
```

How do I get attribute values of `$o` as Array, but just from `class B`, not from `class A`?

When calling `$o->attributes` I get `['a1'=>..., 'a2'=>...,'b1'=>..., 'b2'=>...]`

My expected result is `['b1'=>..., 'b2'=>...]`.

Is there an Yii2-way of doing or do we have to fallback on some PHP functions/language features?

Comment: Don't extend `A`?

Comment: This is part of a large code base...

Comment: make a function ,which return only class B's properties

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848998/how-to-get-all-properties-of-the-current-class-and-not-its-parents-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what attributes you want to get you can name them in first param of [`yii\base\Model::getAttributes()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#getAttributes()-detail) method like this:

```php
$attributes = $o->getAttributes(['b1', 'b2']);
```

If you need all attributes but don't know what attributes are there, you can use [`yii\base\Model::attributes()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#attributes()-detail) method of the parent class to get list of attributes you don't want and pass it as second argument of `getAttributes()` method to leave them out.

```php
$except = A::instance()->attributes();
$attributes = $o->getAttributes(null, $except);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection to enumerate the properties that match the class you want.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

```php
class A extends \yii\base\Model {
    public $a1,$a2;
}

class B extends A {
    public $b1,$b2;
}

$o = new B();

$ref = new \ReflectionClass(B::class);  
$props = array_filter(array_map(function($property) {
    return $property->class == B::class ? $property->name : false; 
}, $ref->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC)));

print_r($props);

/*
Will Print
Array
(
    [0] => b1
    [1] => b2
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset variable `$a1` and `$a2` in class `B` `construct`

```php
...
class B extends A{
  public $b1, $b2;
  
  public function __construct(){
    unset($this->a1, $this->a2);
  }
}
...
```

In my case, when I look up on `$o->attributes`. attribute `a1` and `a2` still exist.

But the variables value become `*uninitialized*` and can't used (`$o->a1` will raise and showed error message).